# How should I test my objects in against each other?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, data-structures

I am creating every data structure In existence and I'm running quint tests. I tested the constructors making sure initially the length is zero and top points to null but testing push.....should I go

```
var stack = new Stack()
var testStack = new Stack()
stack.push(22)
testStack.push(22)
```

then assert they are both equal deeply?

or assert whether stack is deep equal to {Stack: top= Node...etc} Write out what it should be manually?

Comment: What would that test? That the same code does the same thing when you call it twice? Perhaps a good test, depending on what the function does, but not very valuable. All unit tests should test that the code under test does what it should. In other words, a test for `push` should test that the value pushed is in the data structure. Since I don't know what your `push` method does, that's all I can say.

Comment: ok. so assert(stack.top.data, 22)

Comment: Only issue now is that in javascript I'm trying to test the before and after length values of the stack after operations, but they have the same value, even though the stack operations work

Comment: Seems like what you want is to do `var stack = new Stack(); var before = stack.length; stack.push(22); var after = stack.length; assert(after - before, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing some online research for unit testing the structures you are building. For example, here's a snippet of suggestions for testing a stack:

- Create an empty Stack. Test that its size is 0.
- Push an element onto the stack. Test that its size is now 1.
- Push another element onto the stack. Test that its size is now 2.
- Pop an element from the stack. Test that it matches the 2nd pushed
  value. Check that the size of the stack is now 1.
- Pop an element from the stack. Test that it matches the 1st pushed
  value. Check that the size of the stack is 0.
- Attempt to pop an element from the stack when it is empty. [Not sure
  what you expect to do in this situation.]

This was [taken from here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/stack-data-structure-unit-testing), but there are many other sites that will help guide you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing this now. I know aht I said doesn't really make sense upstairs

Comment: It does take a while to develop an "intuition" for what is a good unit test and what is rather meaningless. Keep at it, it is a great skill to develop!